# How to fix TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, mysql-connector-python

I'm setting up a login form using Python/Flask/mysql.connector however I'm getting the error File "F:\Python\Apps\webapp\app.py", line 84, in login
    if result > 0: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'.

I've tried different things like changing the if statement for something different and verifying that dictionary is true, but I get the same error.

```
#Login
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #Get Form
        username = request.form['username']
        password_candidate = request.form['password']

        #Get user by username
        result = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", [username])

        if result > 0:
            #Get stored hash
            data = cursor.fetchone()
            password = data['password']

            #compare the Passwords
            if sha256_crypt.verify(password_candidate, password):
                #Passed
                session['logged_in'] = True
                session['username'] = username

                flash('You are now logged in', 'success')
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
            else:
                error = 'Invalid Login'
                return render_template('login.html', error=error)
            #Close connection
            cursor.close()
        else:
            error = 'Username not found'
            return render_template('login.html', error=error)
    return render_template('login.html')
```

I expected the form to sign you in if the information you use to register is valid or display a fail login if the information is not valid. Obviously this information will be pulled from mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", [username])
```

This line is causing the problem. It is returning you a null value possibly because the username does not exist.

I see you have an `if...else` to handle this, but if the value of result is `None`, you cannot compare it with an integer value - `0` in this case.

In python, you can just check if a value is not `None` by doing this:

```
if result:
    # code
else:
    # code
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: I tried, and got a differnet error, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'convert_to_mysql'

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue.
I changed from `import mysql.connector` to `from flask_mysqldb import MySQL`

Remove the mysql.connector config and added the Database details per the example below

```
 app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
 app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'scott'
 app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
 app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'users'
 app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
```

After that I had to initialize the app

```
mysql = MySQL(app)
```

And the last part was creating a cursor like the example below.

```
cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
```

I also change my if statement to reflect @Harshal Parekh advice.

Instead of

```
    if result > 0:
```

I used

```
    if result:
```

Hopefully this helps somebody else.